Solving $(A+D)X=A$ where $A$ is positive definite and $D$ is diagonal
In my application, I need to solve the linear equation $$(A + D)X = A,$$ where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
I'm interested in characterizing solutions $X$ that are "ill-formed," meaning a single column of $X$ contains both very positive and very negative entries. For example, the matrix  $\left(\begin{matrix} 1&2 \\ -2&4\end{matrix}\right)$ i is "ill-formed" because the first column contains both a large positive entry and a large negative entry. On the other hand, the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$ is not ill-formed because the entries in each column are all positive. This concept is similar in spirit to the idea of multicollinearity in linear regression.
My question is: what properties of $A$ and $D$ lead to "very negative" entries in the solution $X$? I've been able to find examples with small negative entries, but not examples with very negative entries.to use a more specific cutoff of "very negative", what structural properties of $A$ and $D$ would guarantee that the absolute value of the most negative entry in $X$ is at least half as large as the largest positive entry in $X$?
I am particularly interested in intuitive explanations of why certain structures of $A$ and $D$ would lead to ill-formed solutions.

Since $A$ is symmetric positive-definite, we know that it can be written as:
$$A = \Phi\,\Lambda\,\Phi^T$$
where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive diagonal values (eigenvalues of $A$); and $\Phi$ is an orthogonal matrix (eigenvectors of $A$).

Particular case : $\boxed{D \ll A}$
If the entries of $D$ are much smaller than the entries of $A$, $X$ will become the identity matrix. So, for a small $D$, $X$ will never be "ill-formed": $D \ll A \Rightarrow X\approx I$.

Particular case : $\boxed{D = d\,I}$
If $D = d\,I = d\,\Phi\,\Phi^T$, the equation becomes:
$$\left[A+D\right] X = A \Leftrightarrow \Phi\left[\Lambda+d\,I\right]\Phi^T\,X =\Phi\,\Lambda\,\Phi^T \Leftrightarrow \left[\Lambda+d\,I\right] Y = \Lambda$$
where $Y = \Phi^T\,X\,\Phi$ and $X = \Phi\,Y\,\Phi^T$.
$$Y = \left[\Lambda+d\,I\right]^{-1}\,\Lambda$$
This means that $Y$ is a diagonal matrix ($X$ must be diagonalizable by the eigenvectors of $A$), whose entries are given by:
$$Y_{ii} = \frac{\Lambda_{ii}}{\Lambda_{ii}+d}$$
Thus, $X$ must be a symmetric matrix with the same eigenvectors of $A$ and whose eigenvalues are given by $Y$. It will be positive definite whenever $\forall i\,,\,\Lambda_{ii}+d > 0$.

In this case, if $A$ is diagonal, $\Phi = I$, which results in a diagonal $X$. By your definition of "ill-formed", when $D = d\,I$, $X$ will never be "ill-formed" for a diagonal matrix $A$, since in each column, there will be only a non-zero entry.


Example:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\Lambda = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\Phi = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Note that we can write $A$ as:
$$A = \Lambda_{11}\,\phi_1\,\phi_1^T + \Lambda_{22}\,\phi_2\,\phi_2^T$$
where $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the columns of $\Phi$ (eigenvectors of $A$). This results in:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix} + 3\begin{bmatrix}0.5&-0.5\\-0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$
By considering $D = d\,I$, we get $X$ as:
$$X = \frac{1}{1+d}\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix} + \frac{3}{3+d}\begin{bmatrix}0.5&-0.5\\-0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$
To make this "ill-formed" we need to increase the second term, so we can use $d=-3+\varepsilon$:
$$X = \frac{1}{-2+\varepsilon}\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix} + \frac{3}{\varepsilon}\begin{bmatrix}0.5&-0.5\\-0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$
A very low $\varepsilon$ will yield a "perfectly ill-formed" matrix, e.g., $\varepsilon=0.01$ yields:
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}149.75&-150.25\\-150.25&149.75\end{bmatrix}$$
In this example, the property was achieved by using a matrix such that $\phi_2\,\phi_2^T$ is "perfectly ill-formed".

Thanks Daniel. Woudl this be possible of all entries of matrix $A$ are positive?

Yes, you only need an eigenvector such that $\phi,\phi^T$ has only positive entries. For example: $A = 3,\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5\0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix} + 1,\begin{bmatrix}0.5&-0.5\-0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ and $X = d,\begin{bmatrix}1&0\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, with $d = -1+\varepsilon$.

Thanks, just one more condition, if I want to have the diagonal matrix to have only positive entries? so $d>0$ if you want to use $dI$ for example..

Yes, we can obtain "ill-formed" matrices with $d>0$. Take the same example from my answer, and consider $d=\sqrt{3}$ (value that maximizes the difference $\frac{3}{3+d}-\frac{1}{1+d}$): it results in $X = \begin{bmatrix}0.500&-0.134\-0.134&0.500\end{bmatrix}$.
